# Pass Variables or Variable Place-Holder from Editor to PHP

Tags: php, variables, wp-mail

I'm building a method for my client to construct a message content to be sent with wp_mail. Within that I'd like them to be able to choose variables, for example the message might look like this in my admin custom field:

> Email: $email_address$
>
> First Name: $first_name$

So that when I iterate over the lines I can spot a variable place-holder and replace $email_address$ with my variable so my PHP would look like:

```
$body = 'Email Address: name@email.com<br>First Name: Mickey Mouse';
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

I suppose I'm wondering if there's a particular or PHP-ish way to do this, I'm sure I've seen it in plugins before but don't recall the exact formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), which accepts arrays as arguments:

```
$content = "Email: {{email}}\nFirst Name: {{first_name}}";
$body = str_replace(
    ['{{email}}', '{{first_name}}'],
    ['mickey@disney.com', 'Mickey Mouse'],
    $content
);
```

Be careful about using `$` in your placeholders. Since it's widely used in PHP, it's not safe. It was the reason I've used [mustache-like](https://mustache.github.io/) syntax in my example.

Comment: Nice. Thanks, @Cadu. I'll give that a shot.